# Data reset after multiprocess computation

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have a script that will sort a list of hosts and displays the output to screen.
The data comes from a cms using an in-house wrapper and then I sort it to extract the O,. and then feed that to automation tools.

The script was too slow, running for over two minutes.
So we added some parallelism and reduced the execution time to about 40 seconds which is great.

The problem we face now is there is a synchonization problem.
It seems after the pools are closed the data on the sets is reset, and when I print the contents of the set it is empty.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2 
from multiprocessing import Pool
import sys

hostlist_prod = [...]

legacy = set()
rhel67 = set()
other = set()

def sort_host(hostdict):
    if hostdict['os_ver'] is not None:
        if float(hostdict['os_ver']) < 6:
             legacy.add(hostdict['hostname'].lower())
        elif float(hostdict['os_ver']) > 6:
             rhel67.add(hostdict['hostname'].lower())
    else:
        other.add(hostdict['hostname'].lower())

def get_host(hst):
    host = get_cms_all(hst)
    try:
        if len(host) > 1:
            for hostname in host:
                if hostname['software_id'] is not None:
                        sort_host(hostname)
        else:
            sort_host(host[0])
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()



pool = Pool(10)
for hst in hostlist_prod:
    pool.apply_async(get_host, (hst,))
pool.close()
pool.join()

print(legacy)
```

If I add a print in the the `sort_host` function, I see data is added to the set but it seems each process has its own 'version' with different hosts.

How can I get the sets synchronized between all the processes such that the data is available after the processing/sorting is done?

Answer (score 1):

Thats because objects created in one process are not shared with any other process.
You can instead make the sub-processes return all the computed data and combine them in the main process.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import sys



def sort_host(hostdict):
    name = hostdict['hostname'].lower()
    if hostdict['os_ver'] is not None:
        if float(hostdict['os_ver']) < 6:
             return 'legacy', name
        elif float(hostdict['os_ver']) > 6:
             return 'rhel76', name
    else:
        return 'other', name


def get_host(hst):
    host = get_cms_all(hst)
    try:
        sorted_hosts_mapping = set()
        if len(host) > 1:
            for hostname in host:
                if hostname['software_id'] is not None:
                    sorted_hosts_mapping.add(sort_host(hostname))
        else:
            sorted_hosts_mapping.add(sort_host(host[0]))
        return sorted_hosts_mapping
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()


def main():
    hostlist_prod = [...]

    legacy = set()
    rhel67 = set()
    other = set()
    pool = Pool(10)
    sorted_hosts_mappings = pool.map(get_host, hostlist_prod)
    for mapping in sorted_hosts_mappings:
        for entry in mapping:
            key, name = entry
            if key == 'legacy':
                legacy.add(name)
            elif key == 'rhel76':
                rhel67.add(name)
            elif key == 'other':
                other.add(name)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(legacy)


main()
```